# What is the explanation of Sunan Abi Dawud 2146?

Tags: hadith

This is a [hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2146) by Iyas ibn Abdullah

> Iyas ibn Abdullah ibn Abu Dhubab reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as saying:
>
> Do not beat Allah's handmaidens, but when Umar came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: Women have become emboldened towards their husbands, he (the Prophet) gave permission to beat them. Then many women came round the family of the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) complaining against their husbands. So the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Many women have gone round Muhammad's family complaining against their husbands. **They are not the best among you.**

I can't understand who is "They are not the best among you" is referring to.

Is it the woman who are complaining about there husbands or it is there husbands who are beating them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It refers to the husbands. In the hadith, the only one doing something against the advice of the Prophet (SAW) are the husbands.

It ties in with another well-known hadith:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "The best of you is the best to his wives, and I am the best of you to my wives, and when your companion dies, leave him alone." ([Jami At-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/737830))

That is why the Prophet (SAW) says "They are not the best among you."